# label in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, form-for

In my Rails 3.2 project, I have a form to create a new post in `new.html.erb` in `app/views/posts/`

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |post_form| %>
  ...
  <div class="field">
    <%= post_form.label :title %><br />
    <%= post_form.text_field :title %>
  </div>
 ...
  <div class="actions">
    <%= post_form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to display the `title` label as `TITLE`, so I changed the code to `post_form.label :TITLE %>`, but it still displays `Title`. How can I display it as `TITLE`?

Comment: You can directly use Label tag as well or Just pass "TITLE" in string instead of passing :title in the <%= post_form.label :title %>

Comment: In general HTM tag <label class="xyz" for="title">TITLE</label>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a matter of presentation on screen as opposed to content, rather than do the transformation in eruby code, this really ought to be done in CSS:

```
.field label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

If you only want to modify the `:title` input's label rather than all labels having the same class, add a different class or use the input's id in the CSS rule.

If you insist on up-casing it in Rails, use the second parameter to `.label`:

```
<%= post_form.label :title, :title.to_s.upcase %>
```

Comment: Ah okay, I'll use the Rails fix just for now, but will consider the CSS fix later. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the form label as follows:

`<%= post_form.label(:title, "TITLE") %>`

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html